# Need a Oracle Query for Single account_id Mapped With Multiple fund_id

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to work on a data set like below:

```
account_id  Fund_id
    
ASC23454    765432
ASC67654    988776
ASC23454    899098
ASC23454    765787
ASC90878    899877
ASC90878    788978
ASC98765    889909
ASC09876    908990
```

So, I need to write one query in oracle which will display only the `account_id` which has multiple different `fund_id`.

Expected output:

```
account_id  Fund_id
    
ASC23454    765432
ASC23454    899098
ASC23454    765787
ASC90878    899877
ASC90878    788978
```

can anyone please help me to get a query for above output.

Answer (score 2):

Use the analytic `COUNT` function to count the `DISTINCT` number of `fund_id` for each `account_id`:

```sql
SELECT account_id,
       fund_id
FROM   (
  SELECT account_id,
         fund_id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT fund_id) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id) AS num_funds
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  num_funds > 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (account_id, Fund_id) AS
SELECT 'ASC23454', 765432 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASC67654', 988776 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASC23454', 899098 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASC23454', 765787 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASC90878', 899877 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASC90878', 788978 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASC98765', 889909 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ASC09876', 908990 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ACCOUNT_ID | FUND_ID |
| --- | --- |
| ASC23454 | 765432 |
| ASC23454 | 765787 |
| ASC23454 | 899098 |
| ASC90878 | 788978 |
| ASC90878 | 899877 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0X2qvcte)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `EXISTS` subquery grouped by `ACCOUNT_ID` with `HAVING` clause to filter the rows:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   S Q L :
    tbl AS
        ( Select    'ASC23454' "ACCOUNT_ID",    765432 "FUND_ID" From Dual Union All
          Select    'ASC67654', 988776  From Dual Union All
          Select    'ASC23454', 899098  From Dual Union All
          Select    'ASC23454', 765787  From Dual Union All
          Select    'ASC90878', 899877  From Dual Union All
          Select    'ASC90878', 788978  From Dual Union All
          Select    'ASC98765', 889909  From Dual Union All
          Select    'ASC09876', 908990  From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select      t.ACCOUNT_ID, t.FUND_ID  
From        tbl t
Where EXISTS(Select 1 
             From tbl 
             Where ACCOUNT_ID = t.ACCOUNT_ID 
             Group By ACCOUNT_ID Having Count(Distinct FUND_ID) > 1)
```

```sql
/*  R e s u l t : 
ACCOUNT_ID    FUND_ID
---------- ----------
ASC90878       788978
ASC90878       899877
ASC23454       765787
ASC23454       899098
ASC23454       765432   */
```